# Slicing PySpark DataFrame by converting to Pandas DataFrame, Error when converting back to PySpark DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, slice, databricks

I want to slice a PySpark DataFrame by selecting a specific column and several rows as below:

```
import pandas as pd
    
# Data filled in our DataFrame
rows = [['Lee Chong Wei', 69, 'Malaysia'],
        ['Lin Dan', 66, 'China'],
        ['Srikanth Kidambi', 9, 'India'],
        ['Kento Momota', 15, 'Japan']]
  
# Columns of our DataFrame
columns = ['Player', 'Titles', 'Country']
  
# DataFrame is created
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, columns)
  
# Converting DataFrame to pandas
pandas_df = df.toPandas()

# First DataFrame formed by slicing
df1 = pandas_df.iloc[[2], :2]
  
# Second DataFrame formed by slicing
df2 = pandas_df.iloc[[2], 2:]
  
# Converting the slices to PySpark DataFrames
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1, schema = "Country")
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2, schema = "Country")
```

I am running a notebook on Databricks and no need to import Spark Session.

There is an error message `ParseException:`  when running following lines:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1, schema = "Country")
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2, schema = "Country")
```

Please let me know any idea to solve this issue. Full error message is as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4065192899858765> in <module>
     23 
     24 # Converting the slices to PySpark DataFrames
---> 25 df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1, schema = "Country")
     26 df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2, schema = "Country")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    706 
    707         if isinstance(schema, str):
--> 708             schema = _parse_datatype_string(schema)
    709         elif isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
    710             # Must re-encode any unicode strings to be consistent with StructField names

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _parse_datatype_string(s)
    841                 return from_ddl_datatype("struct<%s>" % s.strip())
    842             except:
--> 843                 raise e
    844 
    845 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _parse_datatype_string(s)
    831     try:
    832         # DDL format, "fieldname datatype, fieldname datatype".
--> 833         return from_ddl_schema(s)
    834     except Exception as e:
    835         try:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in from_ddl_schema(type_str)
    823     def from_ddl_schema(type_str):
    824         return _parse_datatype_json_string(
--> 825             sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.fromDDL(type_str).json())
    826 
    827     def from_ddl_datatype(type_str):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    121                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    122                 # JVM exception message.
--> 123                 raise converted from None
    124             else:
    125                 raise

ParseException: 
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'APPLY', 'CALLED', 'CHANGES', 'CLONE', 'COLLECT', 'CONTAINS', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'COPY_OPTIONS', 'CREDENTIAL', 'CREDENTIALS', 'DEEP', 'DEFINER', 'DELTA', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'ENCRYPTION', 'EXPECT', 'FAIL', 'FILES', 'FORMAT_OPTIONS', 'HISTORY', 'INCREMENTAL', 'INPUT', 'INVOKER', 'LANGUAGE', 'LIVE', 'MATERIALIZED', 'MODIFIES', 'OPTIMIZE', 'PATTERN', 'READS', 'RESTORE', 'RETURN', 'RETURNS', 'SAMPLE', 'SCD TYPE 1', 'SCD TYPE 2', 'SECURITY', 'SEQUENCE', 'SHALLOW', 'SNAPSHOT', 'SPECIFIC', 'SQL', 'STORAGE', 'STREAMING', 'UPDATES', 'UP_TO_DATE', 'VIOLATION', 'ZORDER', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ALWAYS', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CATALOG', 'CATALOGS', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODE', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'DAY', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', 'DATABASES', 'DATEADD', 'DATEDIFF', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFAULT', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FN', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GENERATED', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GRANTS', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING', 'HOUR', 'IDENTITY', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INCREMENT', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'ILIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MINUTE', 'MONTH', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON', 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', 'OVER', 'OVERLAPS', 'OVERLAY', 'OVERWRITE', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONED', 'PARTITIONS', 'PERCENTILE_CONT', 'PERCENT', 'PIVOT', 'PLACING', 'POSITION', 'PRECEDING', 'PRIMARY', 'PRINCIPALS', 'PROPERTIES', 'PROVIDER', 'PROVIDERS', 'PURGE', 'QUALIFY', 'QUERY', 'RANGE', 'RECIPIENT', 'RECIPIENTS', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'RECOVER', 'REDUCE', 'REFERENCES', 'REFRESH', 'REMOVE', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPEATABLE', 'REPLACE', 'REPLICAS', 'RESET', 'RESPECT', 'RESTRICT', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', RLIKE, 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'SECOND', 'SCHEMA', 'SCHEMAS', 'SELECT', 'SEMI', 'SEPARATED', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'SESSION_USER', 'SET', 'MINUS', 'SETS', 'SHARE', 'SHARES', 'SHOW', 'SKEWED', 'SOME', 'SORT', 'SORTED', 'START', 'STATISTICS', 'STORED', 'STRATIFY', 'STRUCT', 'SUBSTR', 'SUBSTRING', 'SYNC', 'SYSTEM_TIME', 'SYSTEM_VERSION', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'TBLPROPERTIES', TEMPORARY, 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'TIMESTAMPADD', 'TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'TO', 'TOUCH', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'TRANSFORM', 'TRIM', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TRY_CAST', 'TYPE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'UNBOUNDED', 'UNCACHE', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSET', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VERSION', 'VIEW', 'VIEWS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', 'WITH', 'WITHIN', 'YEAR', 'ZONE', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 7)

== SQL ==
Country
-------^^^
```

Comment: what does the error state exactly?

Comment: I added error message to the question.

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: i see that the slice does not return a dataframe. that might be an issue

Comment: I added [] around column index to get DataFrame by slicing (df1 = pandas_df.iloc[[2], :2]). But, I still get the error.

Comment: your sliced df1 doesn't have schema "country". It only has "Player" and "Titles" as columns. Try giving "Player" or "Titles" or both of those to get spark dataframe. eg spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df1, schema = ["Player"])

Comment: @SrikarDuvvuri, 
Thanks. I revised schema and it was solved.